# nodepad++ support for bash/terminal colors

Tags: notepad++

Can I make notepad++ to color text using the terminal color escape sequences?
For example I have the following text:

`[32m4 tests, 22 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped[0m`

In the terminal it is colored in green, can it be achieved in notepad++ as well?

Thx.

Comment: Have you found some solution?

Comment: @Andris no, I haven't. Instead I found some plugin for vim [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302)